# Flask-Security: Customizing Registration

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, registration, flask-security

I'm trying to use Flask-Security to login and register users. However, I'm trying to do two things. The first being change the default /registration to /signup which I believe I've done correctly. 
The second is I want to customize the registration form. I can get the page loaded but whenever I submit the form nothing happens. No data is sent to the backend or inserted into the sqlite database.

I'm also not sure if I need to write my own app.route function to handle creating a new user and/or checking if they already exist. I'd like to be able to use flask-security's register but just tweak it. If that's even possible.

Here's my main python file:

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, flash, session, request, render_template
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

import os, time


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///data.db'
app.config['DATABASE'] = 'data.db'
app.config['SECURITY_TRACKABLE'] = True
app.config['SECURITY_REGISTERABLE'] = True
app.config['SECURITY_REGISTER_URL'] = '/signup'
app.config['SECURITY_REGISTER_USER_TEMPLATE'] = 'security/register.html'
# enable this if you want to send email and confirm
# app.config['SECURITY_CONFIRMABLE'] = True
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

from user import Security, User, user_datastore
from forms import logform, signupform, RegisterForm

security = Security(app, user_datastore, register_form=signupform,  login_form=logform,
                    confirm_register_form=signupform)

db.create_all()
db.session.commit()


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    log = logform(csrf_enabled=False)
    flash("HELLO.")
    return render_template("index.html", form=log)


@app.route('/login')
def login():
    print "/LOGIN REQUESTED"
    form = logform(csrf_enabled=False)
    return render_template("security/login_user.html", login_user_form=form, security=security)


#not sure if I need this function at all
@app.route('/signup', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def signup():
    print "/SIGNUP REQUESTED"
    form = signupform(csrf_enabled=False)
    # form = RegisterForm()

    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template("security/register.html", register_user_form=form, security=security)

    else:
        #log = logform(csrf_enabled=False)
        if form.validate_on_submit() or form.validate():
            print "HERE NOW SOMEONE SUBMITTED SOMETHING"
            print form.email.data
            print form.username.data
            print form.password.data
            user_datastore.create_user(form)
            db.session.commit()

        return redirect('/')
```

I'm not sure if I need the /signup function or if flask-security will handle it on default. 
Next here's my logform and signupform classes:

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, BooleanField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Length, Email, EqualTo
from flask_security.forms import LoginForm, RegisterForm, Form


class logform(LoginForm):
    login = StringField('login', validators=[DataRequired()])
    # password = PasswordField('password', validators=[DataRequired()])


class signupform(RegisterForm):
    # email = StringField('email', validators=[Email(), DataRequired()])
    username = StringField('username', [DataRequired()])
    # password = PasswordField('password', validators=[DataRequired()])
```

Here's the current registration form I'm trying to use. I'm not sure if I should use url_for('signup') as flask-security's default registration form uses url_for_security('register').

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

    <div id="signup">
        <h1>Create Account.</h1>
        <h3>TESTING</h3>
        {# not sure what to put as my action. default flask-security uses url_for_security('register') #}
        <form id="logfrm" name='register_form' method="POST" action="{{ url_for('signup') }}">
            {# figure out how to make input required #}

            {{ register_user_form.email(placeholder="email", type="email") }}<br>
            {{ register_user_form.username(placeholder="username") }}<br>
            {{ register_user_form.password(placeholder="password", type="password") }}<br>
            {# register_user_form.confirm(placeholder="confirm password") #}<br>
            {{ register_user_form.submit }}
            <input type="submit" value="SIGNUP" >

        </form>
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

Any help would be great, thanks!

---

Thanks for the help. That really cleared up most of the trouble I was having. 
The only other thing wrong was in my form. I was forgetting that `RegisterForm` requires a password confirmation so I also added:
`{{ register_user_form.password_confirm(...) }}`

and to also include a `app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'blah'` in my main file so that the registration doesn't run into an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to define a new route for the registration.

In your `signupform` class that is inherited from `RegisterForm` you only need to override the `validate` method with your custom logic and return `True` or `False` as appropriate.

In your html template for registration the action url is `{{ url_for_security('register') }}`

The same applies for a custom login form - the url action though is `{{ url_for_security('login') }}`